# Backbone.js iterating through JSON results from fetch()

Tags: backbone.js

I am very new to Backbone and just trying to figure out the way things work. How do I iterate through the "fetched" results?

```
(function($) {
    console.log('Formcontainer init.'); 

    var Field = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id: "0",
            memberlist_id: "3",
            field_name: "sample-field-name",
        },
        initialize: function() {
            console.log('Field model init.');
        }
    });

    var FieldCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        defaults: {
            model: Field
        },
        model: Field,
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/getstuff/3.json',
        initialize: function() {
            console.log('FieldCollection init.');
        }
    });

    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#app-container',

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this,"render");
            console.log('ListView init.')
            this.counter = 0;

            this.collection = new FieldCollection();
            this.collection.fetch();
            //this.collection.bind('reset', function() { console.log('xxx')});
            //this.collection.fetch();

            this.render();
        },

        events: {
            'click #add': 'addItem'
        },

        render: function() {
            var self = this;
            console.log('Render called.');
        },

        addItem: function() {
            this.counter++;
            this.$("ul").append("<li>hello world" + this.counter + "</li>");
        }
    });

    var listView = new ListView();

})(jQuery);
```

I get this in my Firebug console:

```
Formcontainer init.
ListView init.
FieldCollection init.
GET http://localhost:8888/getstuff/3.json 200 OK
Render called.
Field model init.
Field model init.
Field model init.
Field model init.
Field model init.
```

It seems that the fetch() was called - since "Field model init." is in the console 5 times. But how to I output that? I would want to append the items in an unordered list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the *reset* event to your *render* function...

```
this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
```

This gets triggered after the *fetch* is complete, so you can create the list...

```
render: function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log('Render called.');
    this.collection.each(function(i,item) {
        this.$el.append("<ul>" + item.get("field_name") + "</ul>");
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks! But where do I put `this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);`? The code I posted only has one "render" function - but in your answer, I do not see the _reset_ event in your _render_ code.

Comment: @wenbert that *bind* call should go in the *initialize* function.  (*Reset* gets called by Backbone after the collection *fetch* is complete.)